# Error on publishing object using Facebook open graph api with facebook C#sdk

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, oauth-2.0

I am using following piece of code to publish my object to facebook using open graph however i am dumbstruck by the following error since 2days.An early reply is very valuable,
Thanks S.

Technology used:Asp.net mvc3 & C#

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient("AppID", "AppSecret");
            fb.AccessToken = "AccessToken";

            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                                 {
                                     {"og:type", "appnamespace:object"},
                                     {"og:url", "objecturl"},
                                     {
                                         "blog", "url-to-post"
                                     }
                                 };

            try
            {
                var Response = fb.Post("https://graph.facebook.com/me/namespace:objecturl", parameters);
            }
            catch (FacebookApiException ex)
            {
            }
```

Exception:
(OAuthException) (#100) Application 276304102435847 does not own 175053105965645 action type

Thanks in advance,
S

Comment: also:i have checked the association of the action and object with application it is all good.The application do own the action and object.The app id and app secret is also correct to application.The association between object and action is also perfectly valid along with the name of object and action.

Comment: FYI :The access token i am using is user access token.

Comment: On more testing I found that when I am using the user access token I am getting the above error but when i go to the facebook graph api explorer and get the application access token and use it i am able to publish to facebook wall.But this won't be a feasible solution because the any user registered on my site should be able to achieve it and so i must use their access token to post to facebook wall of that user.

Comment: Is your action set up in a way that it is only allowed to be published with the app access token by any chance?

Comment: sorry i have no idea regarding that.How can i check that please?

Comment: Go to your actions definition in the app dashboard, and check the “advanced” section at the bottom of the page. The setting is called “Requires App Token to Publish”.

Comment: the Requires App Token to Publish: in the advanced settings is set to no in the application dashboard.So that should not be the reason for the error i think.